# Writing chemical reaction with WP-QuickLaTeX?

Tags: chemfig, mhchem, quicklatex

I want to show series of some chemical reactions on wordpress with [QuickLaTeX](http://www.holoborodko.com/pavel/quicklatex/) using the popular `chemfig` and `mhchem` packages. However, I always encounter some problem.

For example I want to show reaction in series like this:

```
A + B -> C
D + E -> F
and much more like that
```

In Wordpress post I post like this isn't it

```
[latexpage]
\[
\ce{A+B->C} //
\ce{D+E->G}
\]
```

But `//` which creates new line don't work here. I get a single image which looks like this after it is rendered by WP-QuickLaTeX

```
A+B->CD+E->G
```

Is there some way that we can do to WP-QuickLaTeX so it do with codes what we do in LaTeX editor like TeXmaker?

Comment: @clemens it don't work it gives same result as in above post .

Comment: @clemens hmm i don't need that but i want to know is there anyway i write chemical reaction fast and quick in website . I wrote latex code in editor and i got all those reaction in pdf now i need to wrap every equation to show in website using \[....\] is there better way?

Comment: I don't know about Wordpress and line wrapping there. But you should write `\ce{A + B -> C}` (with four spaces). The spaces are important in mhchem syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The code with QuickLaTeX is just the same as you would do in LaTeX as QuickLaTeX uses a TeX Live distribution. The LaTeX code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\[
  xxx \\ yyy
\]

\end{document}
```

just gives one line *xxxyyy* because you cannot have a linebreak in a single equation. This still holds of course when you use `\ce{...}` and it also holds for QuickLaTeX. My guess is that your confusion comes from the fact that on a `[latexpage]` math input with `$...$` and `\[...\]` works natively within a WP post. But there are more possibilities, see below.

If you want alignment with `mhchem` then you can combine it with `amsmath`'s alignment environments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \ce{A + B &-> D} \\
  \ce{C + F &-> X + Y}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same works as QuickLaTeX code for WordPress, too:

```
[latex]
[preamble+]
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
[/preamble]
\begin{align*}
  \ce{A + B &-> D} \\
  \ce{C + F &-> X + Y}
\end{align*}
[/latex]
```

or

```
[latexpage]

\begin{align*}
  [preamble+]\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}[/preamble]
  \ce{A + B &-> D} \\
  \ce{C + F &-> X + Y}
\end{align*}
```

both give on my blog:

[image]

According to QuickLaTeX's homepage the following is valid on a `[latexpage]` so loading of `amsmath` is not necessary in the second case.

> Support of native LaTeX shorthands embedded in the text:
>   `$ ... $`, `\[ ... \]`, `\( ... \)`, `$$ ... $$` and environments: `equation`, `align`, `displaymath`, `eqnarray`, `multline`, `flalign`, `gather`, and `alignat`.